# Generate thousands of JSON documents in Go

Tags: performance, object-oriented, json, go

I recently decided to try to learn the [Go language](https://golang.org/). In order to do this, I wrote a small program which parses a JSON configuration file, and generates N [bson](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson) documents according to its properties.

For example, with this config file:

```
{
    "collection": "test",
    "count": 100,
    "content" : {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullPercentage": 10,
            "length": 8
        },
        "count": {
            "type": "int",
            "nullPercentage": 30,
            "min": 1,
            "max": 200
        },
        "verified": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "nullPercentage": 0
        },
        "firstArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "nullPercentage": 10,
            "size": 3,
            "arrayContent": {
                "type": "string",
                "length": 3
            }
        },
        "firstObject": {
            "type": "object",
            "nullPercentage": 10,
            "objectContent": {
                "key1": { 
                    "type": "string",
                    "nullPercentage": 0,
                    "length": 12
                }, 
                "key2": { 
                    "type": "int",
                    "nullPercentage": 50,
                    "min": 10,
                    "max": 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the program will generate 100000 bson objects which would look like this:

```
{
    "count": 55,
    "firstArray": [
      "tco",
      "nua",
      "uim"
    ],
    "name": "zninfepa",
    "verified": false
  },
  {
    "count": 67,
    "firstArray": [
      "djt",
      "cei",
      "lty"
    ],
    "firstObject": {
      "key1": "nbbogspsvqsw",
      "key2": 19
    },
    "verified": true
  },
  ...
```

These documents are then stored in a database (mongoDB), but I skip that part in this question to focus on the generation of bson documents.
I wrote a small prototype in Java, and then tried to convert it to Go. Here is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"
)

const (
    letterBytes   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

// GeneratorJSON structure containing all possible options
type GeneratorJSON struct {
    // Type of object to genereate. string | int | boolean supported for the moment
    Type string `json:"type"`
    // For `string` type only. Specify the length of the string to generate
    Length int `json:"length"`
    // Percentage of documents that won't contains this field
    NullPercentage int `json:"nullPercentage"`
    // For `int` type only. Lower bound for the int to generate
    Min int `json:"min"`
    // For `int` type only. Higher bound for the int to generate
    Max int `json:"max"`
    // For `array` only. Size of the array
    Size int `json:"size"`
    // For `array` only. GeneratorJSON to fill the array. Need to
    // pass a pointer here to avoid 'invalid recursive type' error
    ArrayContent *GeneratorJSON `json:"arrayContent"`
    // For `object` only. List of GeneratorJSON to generate the content
    // of the object
    ObjectContent map[string]GeneratorJSON `json:"objectContent"`
}

// Collection structure storing global collection info
type Collection struct {
    // Collection name in the database
    Collection string `json:"collection"`
    // Number of documents to insert in the collection
    Count int `json:"count"`
    // Schema of the documents for this collection
    Content map[string]GeneratorJSON `json:"content"`
}

// Generatorer interface for all generator objects
type Generatorer interface {
    // Get a random value according to the generator type. string | int | boolean supported for the moment
    getValue(r rand.Rand) interface{}
    getCommonProperties() CommonProperties
}

// CommonProper interface for commonProperties object ( methods with same behavior for each generator)
type CommonProper interface {
    // Generate a pseudo-random boolean with `nullPercentage` chance of being false
    exist(r rand.Rand) bool
    // Get the key of the generator
    getKey() string
}

// CommonProperties store
type CommonProperties struct {
    key            string
    nullPercentage int
}

// StringGenerator struct that implements Generatorer. Used to
// generate random string of `length` length
type StringGenerator struct {
    common CommonProperties
    length int
}

// IntGenerator struct that implements Generatorer. Used to
// generate random int between `min` and `max`
type IntGenerator struct {
    common CommonProperties
    min    int
    max    int
}

// BoolGenerator struct that implements Generatorer. Used to
// generate random bool
type BoolGenerator struct {
    common CommonProperties
}

// ArrayGenerator struct that implements Generatorer. Used to
// generate random array
type ArrayGenerator struct {
    common    CommonProperties
    size      int
    generator Generatorer
}

// ObjectGenerator struct that implements Generatorer. Used to
// generate random object
type ObjectGenerator struct {
    common        CommonProperties
    generatorList []Generatorer
}

func (c CommonProperties) exist(r rand.Rand) bool { return r.Intn(100) > c.nullPercentage }
func (c CommonProperties) getKey() string         { return c.key }

// getValue returns a random String of `g.length` length
func (g StringGenerator) getValue(r rand.Rand) interface{} {
    by := make([]byte, g.length)
    for i, cache, remain := g.length-1, r.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = r.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            by[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }
    return string(by)
}

// getValue returns a random int between `g.min` and `g.max`
func (g IntGenerator) getValue(r rand.Rand) interface{} { return r.Intn(g.max-g.min) + g.min }

// getValue returns a random boolean
func (g BoolGenerator) getValue(r rand.Rand) interface{} { return r.Int()%2 == 0 }

// getValue returns a random array
func (g ArrayGenerator) getValue(r rand.Rand) interface{} {
    array := make([]interface{}, g.size)
    for i := 0; i < g.size; i++ {
        array[i] = g.generator.getValue(r)
    }
    return array
}

// getValue returns a random object
func (g ObjectGenerator) getValue(r rand.Rand) interface{} {
    m := bson.M{}
    for _, gen := range g.generatorList {
        if gen.getCommonProperties().exist(r) {
            m[gen.getCommonProperties().getKey()] = gen.getValue(r)
        }
    }
    return m
}

func (g StringGenerator) getCommonProperties() CommonProperties { return g.common }
func (g IntGenerator) getCommonProperties() CommonProperties    { return g.common }
func (g BoolGenerator) getCommonProperties() CommonProperties   { return g.common }
func (g ArrayGenerator) getCommonProperties() CommonProperties  { return g.common }
func (g ObjectGenerator) getCommonProperties() CommonProperties { return g.common }

// GetPropertyGenerator returns an array of generator from
// a list of GeneratorJSON
func GetPropertyGenerator(k string, v GeneratorJSON) Generatorer {
    switch v.Type {
    case "string":
        return StringGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}, length: v.Length}
    case "int":
        return IntGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}, min: v.Min, max: v.Max}
    case "boolean":
        return BoolGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}}
    case "array":
        return ArrayGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}, size: v.Size, generator: GetPropertyGenerator("", *v.ArrayContent)}
    case "object":
        var genArr = GeneratePropertyGeneratorList(v.ObjectContent)
        return ObjectGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}, generatorList: genArr}
    default:
        return BoolGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}}
    }
}

// GeneratePropertyGeneratorList create an array of generators from a JSON GeneratorJSON document
func GeneratePropertyGeneratorList(content map[string]GeneratorJSON) []Generatorer {
    genArr := make([]Generatorer, 0)
    for k, v := range content {
        genArr = append(genArr, GetPropertyGenerator(k, v))
    }
    return genArr
}

func main() {
    // Create a rand.Rand object to generate our random values
    var randSource = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    // read the json config file
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./config.json")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File error: %v\n", e)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // map to a json object
    var collection Collection
    err := json.Unmarshal(file, &collection)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // arrays that store all generators
    var genArr = GeneratePropertyGeneratorList(collection.Content)
    // counter for already generated documents
    count := 0
    // array that store 10 bson documents
    var docList [10]bson.M

    for count < collection.Count {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            m := bson.M{}
            // iterate over generators to create values for each key of the bson document
            for _, v := range genArr {
                // check for exist before generating a value to avoid unneccessary computations
                if v.getCommonProperties().exist(*randSource) {
                    m[v.getCommonProperties().getKey()] = v.getValue(*randSource)
                }
            }
            docList[i] = m
            // insert docs in database
            count += 10
        }
    }
    // pretty print last 10 generated Objects
    rawjson, err := json.MarshalIndent(docList, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed")
    }
    fmt.Printf("generated: %s", string(rawjson))
}
```

`go vet` and `golint` both return no warnings for this code. How can this be improved, in terms of readability first, and then in terms of performance?

---

### EDIT

I also created some benchmarks:

test file :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func BenchmarkRandomString(b *testing.B) {
    var randSource = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    stringGenerator := StringGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: "key", nullPercentage: 0}, length: 5}
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        stringGenerator.getValue(*randSource)
    }
}

func BenchmarkRandomInt(b *testing.B) {
    var randSource = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    intGenerator := IntGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: "key", nullPercentage: 0}, min: 0, max: 100}
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        intGenerator.getValue(*randSource)
    }
}

func BenchmarkRandomBool(b *testing.B) {
    var randSource = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    boolGenerator := BoolGenerator{common: CommonProperties{key: "key", nullPercentage: 0}}
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        boolGenerator.getValue(*randSource)
    }
}

func BenchmarkJSONGeneration(b *testing.B) {
    var randSource = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./config.json")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File error: %v\n", e)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var collection Collection
    err := json.Unmarshal(file, &collection)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var genArr = GeneratePropertyGeneratorList(collection.Content)
    var docList [1000]bson.M
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            m := bson.M{}
            for _, v := range genArr {
                if v.getCommonProperties().exist(*randSource) {
                    m[v.getCommonProperties().getKey()] = v.getValue(*randSource)
                }
            }
            docList[i] = m
        }
    }
}
```

and here are the results (`go test -bench=.`):

```
BenchmarkRandomString-4         10000000           221 ns/op
BenchmarkRandomInt-4            30000000            59.2 ns/op
BenchmarkRandomBool-4           50000000            37.8 ns/op
BenchmarkJSONGeneration-4            500       2516883 ns/op
```

And 'real scenario' benchmark (1000000 documents with above config.json file) give this :

```
generating json doc only : 4.5s
generating json doc + inserting in db : 17s
```

---

### Edit 2:

I've spend some time improving this program and open sourced it on github. It's available here:  [feliixx/mgodatagen](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: `// insert docs in database` and `count += 10` should probably be after the next `}` (outside the `for i := 0; i < 10; i++` loop)

Comment: You mentioned "performance" in your last question. Did you run any benchmark? Is the generation so slow in comparison to the insertion into the database? (you could make a buffered channel between one -or more - "document producers" and a "database inserter")

Comment: @oliverpool I added some benchmark results in my edit. Data generation is faster than insertion in database, but still take some time (4.5s for 1000000 docs). Test with `-cpuprofile` show that gccollection take 1/3 of the time, followed by `getValue()` functions, but I don't know how to optimize that. I'll take a look at buffered channels, it seems to be an interesting idea !

Comment: Thanks the for benchmarks: I added performance suggestions in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main, you "iterate over generators to create values for each key". You could actually create a "base" generator for this!

It would be an array generator (10 elements, 0 nullPercentage) of objects (being the objects that you generate).

Using @[ferada's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54571/ferada) leads also to much less code (I also renamed `CommonProper` to `EmptyGenerator`). It uses [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) (one could further optimize, by using the `BoolGenerator` as base - instead of `EmptyGenerator`).

There was a typo on the `exist` function : it should be `>= g.nullPercentage` and not `>` (because `r.Intn(100)` returns between 0 and 99 included).

Here is what I come up with:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

const (
    letterBytes   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

// GeneratorJSON structure containing all possible options
type GeneratorJSON struct {
    // Type of object to genereate. string | int | boolean supported for the moment
    Type string `json:"type"`
    // For `string` type only. Specify the length of the string to generate
    Length int `json:"length"`
    // Percentage of documents that won't contains this field
    NullPercentage int `json:"nullPercentage"`
    // For `int` type only. Lower bound for the int to generate
    Min int `json:"min"`
    // For `int` type only. Higher bound for the int to generate
    Max int `json:"max"`
    // For `array` only. Size of the array
    Size int `json:"size"`
    // For `array` only. GeneratorJSON to fill the array. Need to
    // pass a pointer here to avoid 'invalid recursive type' error
    ArrayContent *GeneratorJSON `json:"arrayContent"`
    // For `object` only. List of GeneratorJSON to generate the content
    // of the object
    ObjectContent map[string]GeneratorJSON `json:"objectContent"`
}

// Collection structure storing global collection info
type Collection struct {
    // Collection name in the database
    Collection string `json:"collection"`
    // Number of documents to insert in the collection
    Count int `json:"count"`
    // Schema of the documents for this collection
    Content map[string]GeneratorJSON `json:"content"`
}

// Generator interface for all generator objects
type Generator interface {
    Key() string
    // Get a random value according to the generator type. string | int | boolean supported for the moment
    Value(r rand.Rand) interface{}
    Exists(r rand.Rand) bool
}

// EmptyGenerator serves as base for the actual generators
type EmptyGenerator struct {
    key            string
    nullPercentage int
}

// Key returns the key of the object
func (g EmptyGenerator) Key() string { return g.key }

// Exists returns true if the generation should be performed
func (g EmptyGenerator) Exists(r rand.Rand) bool { return r.Intn(100) >= g.nullPercentage }

// StringGenerator struct that implements Generator. Used to
// generate random string of `length` length
type StringGenerator struct {
    EmptyGenerator
    length int
}

// Value returns a random String of `g.length` length
func (g StringGenerator) Value(r rand.Rand) interface{} {
    by := make([]byte, g.length)
    for i, cache, remain := g.length-1, r.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = r.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            by[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }
    return string(by)
}

// IntGenerator struct that implements Generator. Used to
// generate random int between `min` and `max`
type IntGenerator struct {
    EmptyGenerator
    min int
    max int
}

// Value returns a random int between `g.min` and `g.max`
func (g IntGenerator) Value(r rand.Rand) interface{} { return r.Intn(g.max-g.min) + g.min }

// BoolGenerator struct that implements Generator. Used to
// generate random bool
type BoolGenerator struct {
    EmptyGenerator
}

// Value returns a random boolean
func (g BoolGenerator) Value(r rand.Rand) interface{} { return r.Int()%2 == 0 }

// ArrayGenerator struct that implements Generator. Used to
// generate random array
type ArrayGenerator struct {
    EmptyGenerator
    size      int
    generator Generator
}

// Value returns a random array
func (g ArrayGenerator) Value(r rand.Rand) interface{} {
    array := make([]interface{}, g.size)
    for i := 0; i < g.size; i++ {
        array[i] = g.generator.Value(r)
    }
    return array
}

// ObjectGenerator struct that implements Generator. Used to
// generate random object
type ObjectGenerator struct {
    EmptyGenerator
    generators []Generator
}

// Value returns a random object
func (g ObjectGenerator) Value(r rand.Rand) interface{} {
    m := bson.M{}
    for _, gen := range g.generators {
        if gen.Exists(r) {
            m[gen.Key()] = gen.Value(r)
        }
    }
    return m
}

// NewGenerator returns a new Generator based on a JSON configuration
func NewGenerator(k string, v GeneratorJSON) Generator {
    eg := EmptyGenerator{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}
    switch v.Type {
    case "string":
        return StringGenerator{EmptyGenerator: eg, length: v.Length}
    case "int":
        return IntGenerator{EmptyGenerator: eg, min: v.Min, max: v.Max}
    case "boolean":
        return BoolGenerator{EmptyGenerator: eg}
    case "array":
        return ArrayGenerator{EmptyGenerator: eg, size: v.Size, generator: NewGenerator("", *v.ArrayContent)}
    case "object":
        return ObjectGenerator{EmptyGenerator: eg, generators: NewGeneratorsFromMap(v.ObjectContent)}
    default:
        return BoolGenerator{EmptyGenerator: eg}
    }
}

// NewGeneratorsFromMap creates a slice of generators based on a JSON configuration map
func NewGeneratorsFromMap(content map[string]GeneratorJSON) []Generator {
    genArr := make([]Generator, 0)
    for k, v := range content {
        genArr = append(genArr, NewGenerator(k, v))
    }
    return genArr
}

func main() {
    // Create a rand.Rand object to generate our random values
    var randSource = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    // read the json config file
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./config.json")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File error: %v\n", e)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // map to a json object
    var collection Collection
    err := json.Unmarshal(file, &collection)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // arrays that store all generators
    generator := baseGenerator(collection.Content)
    // counter for already generated documents
    count := 0
    // array that store 10 bson documents
    var docList []interface{}

    for count < collection.Count {
        docList = generator.Value(*randSource).([]interface{})
        // insert docs in database
        count += generator.size
    }
    // pretty print last 10 generated Objects
    rawjson, err := json.MarshalIndent(docList, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed")
    }
    fmt.Printf("generated: %s", string(rawjson))
}

func baseGenerator(content map[string]GeneratorJSON) ArrayGenerator {
    return ArrayGenerator{
        size: 10,
        generator: ObjectGenerator{
            generators: NewGeneratorsFromMap(content),
        },
    }
}
```

---

**edit regarding the performance**

I don't see simple changes which could drastically improve the speed.

There are some minor changes (from looking at the source of `rand.go`):

```
func (g BoolGenerator) Value(r rand.Rand) interface{} { return r.Int63()&1 == 0 }
```

The `Exists` method could also be faster if it didn't use `Intn`. For instance, it could use the last 7 bits (from 0 to 127) of `Int63` (or multiply the probability by 10 and use the last 10 bits - from 0 to 1023).

**But there is probably a bigger optimization** regarding the generation + insertion in the database.

Currently the data is generated and inserted into the database sequentially. You could do it concurrently with a `record chan bson.M` channel and two goroutines:

- a producer which fills the `record`
- a consumer which inserts them into the database (could be the main goroutine)

Possible code:

```
record := make(chan []interface{}, 3) // 3 is the buffer size
// generate records concurrently
go func() {
    for count < collection.Count {
        record <- generator.Value(*randSource).([]interface{})
        count += generator.size
    }
    close(record)
}()

// save the records
for r := range record {
    _ = r
    // insert record in DB
}
```

If you have a multicore processor, this should improve the overall performance: instead of having 4.5s + 12.5s, it should be much closer to 12.5s (with some overhead for the first run and the synchronization)

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort you put in your answer, it definitely helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A few notes, in general it looks good to me.

- `Generatorer` should probably just be `Generator`, `exist` should be `exists`.  `CommonProper` is harder, perhaps `WithCommonProperties` or `HasCommonProperties`.
- `CommonProperties` doesn't need a `common` name in all the structs, you could simply mention it inline:

  ```
  type StringGenerator struct {
      CommonProperties
      length int
  }
  ```

  Though with that you'll have to mention the name twice when creating the objects, e.g. `StringGenerator{CommonProperties: CommonProperties{key: k, nullPercentage: v.NullPercentage}, length: v.Length}`.

  Also you'll only need one `getCommonProperties` with that: `func (g CommonProperties) getCommonProperties() CommonProperties { return g }` basically.